# webBrowser control opinion for formatted html display

Tags: html, winforms

I am working with content that is carefully formatted HTML entered through an asp.net web application. At the time of deployment we create a database with all of this content for our windows product. Currently we are using the syncfusion HTMLui control to render this content within our software, however that control is no longer displaying the content correctly. As a test case I have recreated one of the forms that we use the HTML content in and replaced all of the syncfusion controls with webBrowser controls, which display the HTML perfectly. So my question is does the web browsers control act the same on different systems. For example will it render the same on XP vs WIN7? Is the control dependent on the version of IE on the users system? Or is the rendering of the webBrowser control the same across all systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx):

> The WebBrowser control is a managed wrapper for the ActiveX WebBrowser
>   control, and uses whichever version of the control is installed on the
>   user's computer.

It will behave differently on different people's PCs. So you need to ensure that your generated html renders appropriately on different versions (within reason), just like you would for any web development.

I can verify this from personal experience as well.  We use it in a handfull of utility apps, and when we were sloppy with css or html, we saw differences among different clients.